# zend framework plug-in - predispatch()

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins, zend-framework-mvc

I wrote a plugin with predispatch() method to check access rights on each controller request . I have made plugin as :

class My_Plugin_Checklogin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
    public function preDispatch() {

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['Zend_Auth_Static'])) {
        //no login
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        //the request
        $request->setModuleName('default');
        $request->setControllerName('index');
        $request->setActionName('index');
        //send to default/login/index
    }
}
```

}

It's calling predispatch() before each controller request now.

But also not allowing me to log in. always keeping me on login page due to predispatch method. How I have to set predispatch method.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to skip this plugin for a particular controller (and/or action) is to add a conditional at the beginning of the plugin's `preDispatch()` method

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    if ($request->getModuleName() == 'default' 
     && $request->getControllerName() == 'login'
     && $request->getActionName() == 'index') {
        return ;
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['Zend_Auth_Static'])) {
       // your code goes here
    }
}
```